# How do I modify the alt+[key] special character mappings?

Tags: keyboard, macos, preferences, internationalization

So pressing alt+[any key] gives you a special character. I am wondering if there is a way to change what special character is outputted for every alt+[key] keystroke. For example, I would like to map alt+t to the theta symbol, map alt+d to the degree symbol, and map alt+s to the square root symbol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to do what you need is probably to just set up text replacements in: System Preferences > Keyboard > Text > Replace With

If you really want to change key mappings, you can use [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele), or possibly [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/).

Comment: The 1st method will force you to put a space before the strings to be replaced, and this is not always convenient.

Comment: @daniel Azuelos, Using the first method, I **did not** have to, nor was I forced to "put a space before the strings to be replaced". What version of OS X/macOS are you running? The first method is certainly easier then using Ukelele, however if one wants a permanent method (until the layout is changed again) that just types the designated character presenting no other choice, then Ukelele is the way to go.

Comment: The text replacement is not universal. only works with apps made by Apple (ex: Safari). It won't work for MS Word.

Comment: @btrballin Word has its own text replacement settings

Comment: Thanks. Ukelele is great and now I am able to use a custom keyboard that prints different special characters for certain alt+key keystrokes